# Find reminder between 2 floating numbers using fmod()

Tags: php, modulus, fmod

I was trying to validate if the first floating number could be fully divided by the second floating number and I got something like these:

```
$first = 10.20; // or 5.10, 7.14, 9.18
$second = 1.02;

var_dump(fmod($first, $second));

// output is showing
float(1.02)
```

But if I try to divide below these numbers by 1.02 `fmod()`works nicely.I don't understand why`fmod()` behaving like this? Any answer to this question will help me to understand the fact.

```
$first = 4.08; // or 2.04, 3.06, 6.12, 8.16
$second = 1.02;

var_dump(fmod($first, $second));

// output is showing
float(0)
```

Comment: Topic to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `fmod()` function only returns the floating point modulos of the division made.

As in your first case the remainder is a floating point value it is returned by the function.

But in the below examples if we make divisions as

```
$first = 4.08; // or 2.04, 3.06, 6.12, 8.16
$second = 1.02;
```

We get the remainder as of type integer which is **0.041616**.The problem here is the values shown by the function are limited only till the first decimal(in this case it is `0.0`).But if we had to find the modulos of two numbers as

```
<?php
$x = 5.7;
$y = 1.3;
$r = fmod($x, $y);
?>
```

We will get the values as **float(0.5)**.

Because the here the first digit after decimal point is not 0.

And hence in your case it is shown `float(0)` by the function.

For more details you can visit [Click Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php)